# Excluding “ when using StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4

Tags: java, sanitize, html-sanitizing, stringescapeutils

I am trying to Sanitize the requestBody. For this purpose I am converting Object to Json and then passing the Json to

```js
requestBody

{
  "data": {
    "id": "123",
    "unit_id": "456",
    "country": "jp",
    }
}
```

StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml

Output post escaping:

```js
{&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;123&quot;,&quot;unit_id&quot;:&quot;456&quot;,&quot;country&quot;:&quot;jp&quot;}}
```

It is escaping the double quotes(“) which is breaking the Json structure when I am trying convert the Json back to Object.

How I can exclude double quotes(“) alone during this process?

Comment: Can you add what you have now as json and what you expect to the question?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle will that information help?